# How to pass row values from iframe popup to parent page textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, iframe

I am creating a website using asp.net. I want to take get row values from iframe popup to parent page textboxes. How can i do it? Any help would be appreciated.

My parent page like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content" runat="server">
<asp:FormView ID="DataInsert" runat="server">
<div class="row-fluid">
 <div class="span6">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">SerialNumber:</label>
       <div class="controls">
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtSerialNum" runat="server" Enabled="false" Text="<%#BindItem.SERIAL_NUM">"</asp:TextBox>
      </div>
       </div>
      <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">StockNumber:</label>
       <div class="controls">
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtStockNum" runat="server" Enabled="false" Text="<%#BindItem.STOCK_NUM">"</asp:TextBox>
      </div>
       </div>
      </div>
       </div>
      </asp:Formview>
       <div id="responsive" class="modal hide fade">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
               <iframe id="PhoneFrame" src="<%= ResolveClientUrl(~pages/Phone.aspx)" %>" </iframe>
          </div>
       </div>
      </div>
       </div>
        </asp:Content>
```

And phone.aspx is like this:

```
<asp:Gridview ID="phoneGrid" runat="server"
 SelectMethod= .....
  OnPreRender=......
   OnRowDataBound=..... etc.
   <Columns>
   <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Phone Serial Number:" DataField="P_SERIAL_NUM" />
     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Phone Stock Number:" DataField="P_STOCK_NUM" />
      <ItemTemplateField>
       <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Button ID="btnChoose" Text="Choose" OnClientClick="btnChooseClick()" />
           </ItemTemplateField>
       </ItemTemplate>
      </Columns>
      </asp:GridView>
```

What should I use for transfer method?

Answer (score 0):

[Window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) is a potential good way to achieve this.

Have a look to this [example](https://robertnyman.com/html5/postMessage/postMessage.html).